# How do I use <input type="date"> with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an uploadPage and would like to use a date picker for one of the inputs. Everything works fine, but when I press submit nothing happens. I tried switching the input to "number" rather than "date" and it worked. But date seems to not be working. I have a feeling it has to do with the useState? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, message, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload'
import Axios from 'axios';

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "1" },
    { key: 2, value: "2" },
    { key: 3, value: "3" },
    { key: 4, value: "4" },
    { key: 5, value: "5" },
    { key: 6, value: "6" },
    { key: 7, value: "7" }
]

function UploadProductPage(props) {

    const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("")
    const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("")
    const [DateValue, setDateValue] = useState([])
    const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState(1)

    const [Images, setImages] = useState([])


    const onTitleChange = (event) => {
        setTitleValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onDateChange = (event) => {
        setDateValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
        setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const updateImages = (newImages) => {
        setImages(newImages)
    }
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();


        if (!TitleValue || !DescriptionValue || !DateValue ||
            !ContinentValue || !Images) {
            return alert('fill all the fields first!')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: props.user.userData._id,
            title: TitleValue,
            description: DescriptionValue,
            date: DateValue,
            images: Images,
            continents: ContinentValue,
        }

        Axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('Product Successfully Uploaded')
                    props.history.push({
                        pathname: "/user/cart",
                        state: {
                          data: variables,
                        }, 
                      })
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload Product')
                }
            })

    }

    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2}> Upload Prompt </Title>
            </div>


            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} >

                {/* DropZone */}
                <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} />

                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Subject</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onTitleChange}
                    value={TitleValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onDescriptionChange}
                    value={DescriptionValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Due Date</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onDateChange}
                    value={DateValue}
                    type="date"
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Continents</label>
                <br /><br />
                <select onChange={onContinentsSelectChange} value={ContinentValue}>
                    {Continents.map(item => (
                        <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>{item.value} </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />

                <Button
                    onClick={onSubmit}
                >
                    Submit
                </Button>

            </Form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

Comment: unrelated question: why are you using boatloads of `<br/>` instead of using CSS to properly space your form fields?

Comment: I’m still learning. I will look into this, thanks